# How to infuse coconut flavor into nuts?

Tags: nuts, coconut, infusion, flavor

While traveling abroad, I purchased a small bag of salted cashews at a convenience store.  I immediately noticed that they have a distinctively different taste from what I'm used to; slightly more sweet than salty.

I took a look at the back of the package and found the ingredients list; to my surprise, it ended with "coconut cream".  Thinking of all the coconut-flavored dishes that I've had at home, I immediately recognized that the distinctive taste was from the coconuts.

However, coconut dishes I've had at home usually consist of something cooked in a coconut-based broth.  Other than dried coconut chips, I can't think of any "dry" coconut flavor food I've eaten or cooked.

Starting with raw cashews or other nuts, how can I prepare a product of these nuts infused with coconut flavor?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is the use of coconut oil in frying the cashews.

Comment: if the ingredients list **ended** with coconut cream, it didn't take much. Probably just a coating (after roasting) that is then dried.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar, although not with coconut cream. I'd cook the nuts in whatever flavored mixture (with extra salt and sugar) for about 5 min, then leave them soaking for a few hours. After that I'd bake them in the oven with low heat, like 170 C (otherwise you'd burn them very easily). Check every 5 min and toss them around a bit to even up, and depends on how moist they are, take out when brown and crisp in the center.

Answer (score -1):

This is really simple to do. Get a high quality coconut oil that is Hydrogenated. And pour 16oz of nuts into 1-2 tablespoons of oil. Mix around in bowl and let sit for a few hours in the refrigerator. Pour them onto a paper towel or clean cloth and let the excess oil be soaked up.